# catch forEach last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
arr = [1,2,3];
arr.forEach(function(i){
// last iteration
});
```

How to catch when the loop ending? I can do `if(i == 3)` but I might don't know what is the number of my array.

Comment: It's a good question, pratically doesn't exists a way to program without handle that.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

See also an [updated answer for ES6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688391/272287).

---

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]; 

arr.forEach(function(elem, idx, array){
   if (idx === array.length - 1){ 
       console.log("Last callback call at index " + idx + " with value " + elem ); 
   }
});
```

would output:

```
Last callback call at index 2 with value 3
```

The way this works is testing `arr.length` against the current index of the array, passed to the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters).

Answer (score 46):

**The 2021 ES6+ ANSWER IS**:

```
    const arr = [1, 2, 3];

    arr.forEach((val, key, arr) => {
      if (Object.is(arr.length - 1, key)) {
        // execute last item logic
        console.log(`Last callback call at index ${key} with value ${val}` ); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: I like this one better today - although I'll readily admit even back in 2015 implicitly declaring a global was a bad idea.

Comment: Huhh... The previous version is much more concise and readable. This Object stuff is a mess.

Comment: It's only a mess if you don't understand it Giorgio79.  There are numerous benefits to using Object.is() as your primary method of comparison versus == or ===. Thanks for your comment, however!

Comment: @SterlingBourne can you explain further what those benefits are? (It'd be good to include that in the answer too)

Comment: Using `Object.is` for something as simple as somparing two integers (that cannot even be -0 or NaN) is most definitely messy. Tell me, @SterlingBourne, what are the benefits?

Comment: Consistency. You don't have to use spaces or tabs for new lines, but we do it to make our code less prone to errors. Using Object.is() every time, even for something as comparing two integers, prevents mistakes in the future when something can be NaN or -0. Why take the risk?

Comment: @SterlingBourne - have two questions: 1. Why do you need functions invocation in places where there could be only identity comparison?(function invocations more costly) 2. Isn't there some problem in the application up the line if you expect a number(for example) and get NaN and shouldn't you catch it earlier than invoking Object.is?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this way:

```
arr.forEach(function(i, idx, array){
   if (idx + 1 === array.length){ 
       console.log("Last callback call at index " + idx + " with value " + i ); 
   }
});
```

Seems Like more positive

Answer (score 4):

```
const arr= [1, 2, 3]
arr.forEach(function(element){
 if(arr[arr.length-1] === element){
  console.log("Last Element")
 }
})
```

Comment: Might not always work. `let o = { val:"ue" } ; let arr = [ o, 1, o ]; ...` unfortunately the first iteration will have `arr[arr.length-1] === element`